# How to debug a react-native package?

Tags: debugging, react-native, package

This is a react-native package, [epubjs-rn](https://github.com/futurepress/epubjs-rn). This package is old and the error it is showing seems solvable.

So, I would like to debug and see if I can solve the problem I am facing.

*File Structure for `node_modules/epubjs-rn`*

[image: file structure inside epubjs-rn]

It seems as, my edits in files inside `src` folder is not showing any effect as the files from `components` folder are used in the import.

What shall I do to debug this react-native package?
Is there a way to recompile the changes in `src` folder? What approach should I follow to improve this package?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used to do:

> Move ready-to-modify-module from `node_modules` to your own folder,
>   then make your own version there.

There are some reasons to do so:

1. The way to `import` that module is almost same as inside of `node_modules`. Only difference could be that you have to provide related path. example:

   ```
   import { EPub } from './../MY_OWN_FOLDER/epubjs-rn-my-version';
   ```
2. It's more safe, since your modified code will be overwritten by redo `npm install` again.

Comment: For this exact package, I was unable to make it work by copying it to another folder. But editing the files inside `components` directly helped, though it was in old version of ECMAscript.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the import was being done from `components` folder, while I was debugging by making changes inside `src`. So, making changes in files inside `components` folder did the trick.